# The correct tool for testing statistically likely source of endpoint?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, linear, multivariate-regression

**Background**

Whilst I have some experience in statistics, I am not trained in the field and so am at somewhat of a loss with respect to what tool I should employ in the following scenario.

I have a range of products, say, [A ... Z] which require a number of constituent components to be produced over a number of stages. I know what the constituent components are and the quantity of each required to do this. This is unchanging.

I have access to the complete stock (numbers and location) of all products. I also have access to data which enumerates the production and exchange of components. I do not have access to data which tracks individual components. That is, I can only track components as grouped batches.

**Aim**

My aim is twofold. First, to predict the likelihood of a base component being produced in a given area for the purposes of creating a given product. That is to say, which areas are most used in production for any product.

Secondly, once this has been found, I am trying to predict the likelihood a base component will be used in product A over, say, product Z or any other product.

A base component is the foundational component to produce all subsequent components, which are then used in turn to produce a product.

**Analogy (not required to read but may help in explaining)**

By way of analogy, let us say the city of Ankh-Morpok produces a number of items including the foobar and the boofar. The foobar ultimately requires 400 giblits, which are either used directly as components or made into other components (which again may be used in other components). The boofar ultimately requires 250 giblits. Each giblit must be extracted from the ground. Giblits are ubquitously available across the city.

My aim is to find which district of the city is likely to extract the most giblets over x time period. And also to predict where a giblit will likely end up; a foobar or a boofar over the same time period. It might seem the foobar would be the answer, but the boofar may be produced in larger quantities, for example, or larger time periods may cause greater stability or fluctuation.

**Current attempt**

From what little I know, my understanding is that I would require some kind of regression to predict the likely place of origin and likely final product for a given base component. I have been trying to read through statistics workbooks to contextualise my problem and see something similar but as time has gone on, I am under the impression that my question does not have a clear explanatory and response variable. I thought place would be the explanatory variable but perhaps I am wrong here.

Moreover, I am not sure which type of regression (if regression is indeed the correct tool) I should be using. When I read upon the different types, owing to the sheer number of components, places, and products, multivariate linear regression seemed the most apt so I have been working towards learning this, but is this correct?

**Question**

In the briefest possible terms, is multivariate linear regression the most apt tool for the scenario outlined above? If not, could you suggest materials for me to read, or a better suited tool or approach for the job?

Thank you very much for taking the time to read through this. I appreciate any and all responses.

Comment: Is it possible to have the dataset? I can try to resolve and show you a way. Jm

Comment: Hi @Jmbonni unfortunately, the dataset is under NDA. Is there another way I can present the data which would be useful? I could perhaps create a mock example if that would help? Or if there is anything that needs clarifying, more than happy to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is a statistical problem. Suppose you know that 1000 cars have been made, using 10,000 kg of rubber; and 10,000 wellington boots have been made, using 5,000 kg of rubber. Then 1/3 of the rubber has been used to make boots.

Statistical methods are used when there is randomness - I didn't see any randomness in the problem as you describe it.

Comment: Hi @chrishmorris, sorry I should have been clearer. What is static are the 'ingredients', so to speak, of each product. The randomness is in predicting future trends regarding the origin of materials and what they end up as. So how do we know rubber produced in location X will produce primarily cars, and how certain can we be of this? Similarly, how can we know a greater proportion of rubber will come from location Y over location X in the production of cars for example, and how certain can we be of this?

Comment: So the demand for products varies over time? And the figures you have for past demand are regarded as a sample from a distribution? And the question is, given this distribution, what is the distribution of e.g. "% of rubber from Malaya that becomes part of cars"?

Comment: Hi @chrishmorris. That is correct, the demand will vary. The past demand figures are the population data, not a sample. The question as you put it is correct; that is, how may I predict this and with what degree of confidence. Thank you very much for your help so far!

Comment: The problem here is that the transformation from the varying demand to the values you want to predict is complicated, so you are unlikely to get a closed form solution. You therefore need to do a simulation, then display the distribution of values from the simulation. The remaining choice is how to provide the demand to the simulation. If you have lots of data, then just use random samples from the actual data. If the actual data fits a well known distribution, then you can use samples from that distribution. If neither holds, then I would use samples from the actual data plus random noise.

Comment: Hi @chrishmorris. Sincere apologies for the delay, I was away and then forgot to reply. Thank you for the comment. I have marked your response as the answer. So if I have it right, the simulation removes potential complexities and then I feed the demand in from whichever is the case according to the three options you stated? Just to be clear, would the simulation simulate supply or something else too? Thank you very much for your help thus far and my apologies again.

Comment: Yes, simulate the supply.

Comment: Great, thank you very much for that. I will probably use random samples from the population although I will also check if it fits a well known distribution too, as per your suggestion.